# How to update fwupdmgr itself

Tags: fwupd

I am trying to update my firmware on Ubuntu 18.04. When I try to see updates with

`$ fwupdmgr get-updates`

I see the following:

```
$ fwupdmgr get-updates 
Not compatible with org.freedesktop.fwupd version 1.0.9, requires >= 1.2.5
No upgrades for UEFI Device Firmware, current is 192.47.1524: 192.47.1524=same
Not compatible with org.freedesktop.fwupd version 1.0.9, requires >= 1.1.0
Not compatible with org.freedesktop.fwupd version 1.0.9, requires >= 1.1.3
```

This suggests to me that my `fwupdmgr` version (which is `1.0.9`) needs to be upgraded to at least `1.2.5` to apply all of the available updates.

How can I update `fwupdmgr`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install the `fwupd` snap to get a newer version:

```
sudo apt remove fwupd
snap install fwupd
```

You will get 1.3.6 at the time of writing

That's what I did at least (I'm also on 18.04), to be able to install the latest firmware updates on my Thinkpad X1 Carbon Gen6.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04 you need to run `sudo snap install fwupd --classic`, because this revision of snap "fwupd" was published using classic confinement.

Answer (score 2):

If possible upgrade to 19.10 and you would have 1.2.10

> Package fwupd

```
bionic (18.04LTS) (admin): Firmware update daemon    1.0.6-2ubuntu1
eoan (19.10) (admin): Firmware update daemon    1.2.10-1ubuntu2
```

In case that is not an option you could try to install the [debian install file from 19.10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/amd64/fwupd/download) either manually through `dpkg` or the software center and then pick all the dependencies needed as instructed during the attempt to install. The list of requirements is [pretty long](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/amd64/fwupd).

Next best thing is to install it from source and use that version.

Main components of the [compilation instructions](https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/wiki/Compilation):

```
# apt build-dep fwupd
# meson build
```

I don't believe it to be a good idea to do this other then from a newer version of Ubuntu. We are talking about updating device drivers. Those are also connected to the kernel so upgrading from within 18.04 might have you end up installing things from 19.10 anyways.

Answer (score 1):

`snap install fwupd` didn't work for me on 18.04 but `sudo snap install fwupd --candidate --classic` did. This installed 1.3.8 because updates on a T480 don't seem to work any more with version 1.2.x that comes with 18.04.

Comment: Interestingly enough, in Ubuntu 20.04, installing with `--candidate` gives you an older version (1.3.8) than without it (1.5.7 ) as of Feb 2021!